# Merging two dataframes using closest lower value in R

Tags: r, loops, merge

I have extracted partial information from two dataframes as below:

```
df1 <- data.frame(sample=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                       RT=c(3.88, 4.52, 32.82, 15.71, 20.33),
                       Hit=c(2, 1, 7, 1, 5))
```

and

```
df2 <- data.frame(rt_stand=c(4.5, 8.5, 15.8, 23.2, 35.0),
                       n_carb=c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14),
                       below=c(5.5, 6.8, 8.2, 10.0, 12.3))
```

I would like the rows from df2 to join the rows of df1 based on the **nearest but lower value**.

Output would be a dataframe as such:

| sample | RT | Hit | rt_stand | n_carb | below |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.88 | 2 | NA | NA | NA |
| 2 | 4.52 | 1 | 4.5 | 10 | 5.5 |
| 3 | 32.82 | 7 | 23.2 | 13 | 10.0 |
| 4 | 15.71 | 1 | 8.5 | 11 | 6.8 |
| 5 | 20.33 | 5 | 15.8 | 12 | 8.2 |

Above is a small reproducible example. I believe that to deal with the entire data set, I will need to create a loop that binds/merges df2 rows to df1 based on a function that finds a minimum but smaller number.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nearest but lower value of which variable? Are you comparing `RT` of `df1` with `rt_stand` of `df2` ?

Comment: A rolling join? I'm not too clear on the logic you're expecting: `library(data.table); setDT(df1); setDT(df2); df2[df1, on="rt_stand==RT", roll=TRUE]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fuzzyjoin` package to keep rows where `RT` is greater than `rt_stand` and for each `sample` keep the closest value.

```
library(dplyr)

fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_inner_join(df1, df2, by = c('RT' = 'rt_stand'), 
                            match_fun = `>`) %>%
  arrange(sample, rt_stand) %>%
  group_by(sample) %>%
  slice(n()) %>% 
  ungroup -> result

result
# A tibble: 4 x 6
#  sample    RT   Hit rt_stand n_carb below
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1      2  4.52     1      4.5     10   5.5
#2      3 32.8      7     23.2     13  10  
#3      4 15.7      1      8.5     11   6.8
#4      5 20.3      5     15.8     12   8.2
```

Note that the above `result` does not have `sample = 1` since there is no `RT` value which is greater than `rt_stand` for that `sample`. To get all the `sample` values you can then do :

```
df1 %>%
  filter(!sample %in% result$sample) %>%
  bind_rows(result)

#  sample    RT Hit rt_stand n_carb below
#1      1  3.88   2       NA     NA    NA
#2      2  4.52   1      4.5     10   5.5
#3      3 32.82   7     23.2     13  10.0
#4      4 15.71   1      8.5     11   6.8
#5      5 20.33   5     15.8     12   8.2
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked great and fuzzyjoin is extremely helpful!